# ASP.NET: Button Outside UpdatePanel Fails to PostBack

Tags: asp.net-ajax, button, drop-down-menu, updatepanel

I have a donation form that contains an update panel that contains a dropdown for predetermined amounts plus the "Other" option".  When "Other" is selected the dropdown has triggered the partial postback and renders the update panel with the additional "Other" textbox for the amount.  Outside this update panel I have a additional server control form fields such as textboxes and a button for submission.

The bug I run into is when "Other" is selected the button "onclick" event fails to fire a full postback.

Example:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanelAmount" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <table style="width: 500px;">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 200px;"><asp:Label ID="lblAmount" runat="server" CssClass="required" Text="Donation Amount: " /></th>
            <td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="selAmount" runat="server" />
                <asp:CustomValidator ID="valDonationAmount" runat="server" ControlToValidate="selAmount" ErrorMessage="Donation Amount" Display="None" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>        
        <asp:Panel ID="panelOther" runat="server" Visible="false">
            <table style="width: 500px;">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th style="width: 200px;"><asp:Label ID="lblOther" runat="server" Text="Other Amount: " /></th>
                <td>
                    $<asp:TextBox ID="txtOther" runat="server" />
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="valOther" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtOther" Display="None" ErrorMessage="Other Amount" Enabled="false" />
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="valOtherExpress" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtOther" Display="None" ErrorMessage="Other Amount: Invalid" ValidationExpression="[1-9][0-9]+(\.[0-9]{2})?" Enabled="false" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
        </asp:Panel>                
    </ContentTemplate>           
</asp:UpdatePanel>    
<ctl:CreditCardForm ID="ctlCreditCardForm" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Donate" />
```

EDIT: Posting the code-behind might make is easier for everyone

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private ArrayList _donations;

    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        valDonationAmount.ServerValidate += new ServerValidateEventHandler(valDonationAmount_ServerValidate);        
        selAmount.AutoPostBack = true;
        selAmount.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(selAmount_SelectedIndexChanged);
        updatePanelAmount.UpdateMode = UpdatePanelUpdateMode.Conditional;
        updatePanelAmount.ChildrenAsTriggers = true;
        btnSubmit.Click += new EventHandler(btnSubmit_Click);
    }

    void selAmount_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (selAmount.SelectedItem.Text == "Other")
        {
            panelOther.Visible = true;
            valOther.Enabled = true;
            valOtherExpress.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            panelOther.Visible = false;
            valOther.Enabled = false;
            valOtherExpress.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    void valDonationAmount_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        args.IsValid = true;
        if (args.Value == "0")
        {
            args.IsValid = false;
        }
    }

    void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.Validate();                 
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {

        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    
        _donations = new ArrayList();
        double[] donations = new double[] { 20.00, 50.00, 100.00, 250.00, 500.00 };
        _donations.AddRange(donations);

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            foreach (Double d in _donations)
            {
                selAmount.Items.Add(new ListItem(String.Format("{0:c}", d), String.Format("{0:c}", d)));
            }
            selAmount.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Donation Amount","0"));
            selAmount.Items.Add(new ListItem("Other", "Other"));
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: I looked under a different example (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180366/losing-button-click-events-after-first-partial-postback-in-updatepanel) that setting "btnSubmit.UseSubmitBehavior = false" is suppose to fix the problem.  I'm not finding that it does.

Comment: I keep testing it and finding something interesting.  When the update panel renders from dropdown selection of "Other", I click on the button with observing any triggered requests with FireBug and nothing.  But, when I give txtOther a value, I get a postback.  I don't understand that.  Anyone know?

Comment: That last comment sounds really freaky. Could this be a browser bug, maybe? Which browser are you using? Have you tried it in others? Also, what behaviour do you get if you get rid of the UpdatePanel (i.e. do everything in full postback)?

Comment: In FireFox 3 and Internet Explorer 7, it behaves the same.  I tried it in Google Chrome and the behavior is different.  Autopostback on dropdown doesn't update the panel or I'm not sure if it is sending a request.  I'll try and strip out the updatepanel and see what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this possibly a validator blocking you?  Is your button supposed to ignore any validators? If so, you should set CausesValidation="false" on the button so that it will fire even if the validators in the panel are invalid.

Otherwise, the button's click event will be stopped by the validators in the panel.

Comment: Yes! This would explain why I could do the following: 

            $('#<%=btnSubmit.ClientID %>').click(function() {
                __doPostBack('<%=btnSubmit.UniqueID %>', '');
            });

It must of been a client-side script keeping the postback from happening.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I wanted to know why instead of using the workaround.  I should of traced through the generated JS more.  Might have found the answer.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX causes some funky behavior with postbacks, session, etc.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Donate" onClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
```

Edit: Also try this: Make sure your wire-up isn't in an "if (!isPostBack)" block.

Answer (score 0):

Put below code outside of your update panel.

```
<%--dummy validator to make ajax validation possible--%>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" CssClass="hidden" ControlToValidate="dummyTextBox" ValidationGroup="dummy"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="dummyTextBox" CssClass="hidden"></asp:TextBox>

        <style>
    .hidden {
      display: none;
    }
    </style>
```

Below link worked for me....

http://jeffreypaarhuis.com/2011/08/08/validation-not-working-in-updatepanel/

Answer (score -3):

Check the AutoPostBack property of the Button control. Set it to "True".

Comment: Buttons are AutoPostback by default.